Por que no me deja abrir una ventana con tk?
import tkinter as tk

ventana = tk.Tk()
ventana.geometry("500x500")

perdonad si parezco tonto pero en vs code no me quiere abrir una ventana nueva con tk

Estaría faltantando al final
ventana.mainloop()

para que muestre la pantalla.

tienes toda la razón ahora que lo dices tiene todo el sentido del mundo
